# How to identify controller,view from url when using yii framework

Tags: php, yii

My questions is how to identify controller or view from URL?

For example in codeigniter from URL -localhost/projectname/controller/index we can identify controller and its function just like that. How can I identify when using yii framework?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL will look something like this (if routing is turned off):

```
www.example.com/index.php?r=controller/action
```

If routing is turned on, than by default it will look like this:

```
www.example.com/controller/action
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply,
my link is http://localhost/limesurvey/index.php/admin/survey/sa/index so now which is controller and which is action?

Comment: Look at your routing in config. I assume it's `sa/index` as `controller/action`